# Send AWS S3 Events in CloudWatch to my server using Lambda in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, apache-httpclient-4.x, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to send a S3 event log to my server outside AWS in case of object level API call is triggered in my bucket using Lambda (upload, download, etc) but when I run it it returns timeout without any error mentioned. I suspect maybe it is because it can't send it to my server using HttpClient but not entirely sure.

Here is my Lambda function:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord;

public class S3EventProcessor implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

    public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
        S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);
        String event = record.toString();
        String url = "http://myexampleserver.com";



HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(event);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        entity.setContentType("text/plain");
        post.setEntity(entity);
        context.getLogger().log("Setting up post request");

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
             response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        context.getLogger().log(Integer.toString(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
        String a = "Event: " +  s3event.getRecords().get(0).getRequestParameters().getSourceIPAddress();
        return a;
    }

}
```

Is my Lambda function correct?

Here is my log and error messsage:

```
START RequestId: bea1b956-3f9b-11e7-93c8-5503fb925252 Version: $LATEST
Setting up post requestEND RequestId: bea1b956-3f9b-11e7-93c8-5503fb925252
REPORT RequestId: bea1b956-3f9b-11e7-93c8-5503fb925252  Duration: 30001.43 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB  
2017-05-23T09:40:21.181Z bea1b956-3f9b-11e7-93c8-5503fb925252 Task timed out after 30.00 seconds
 "errorMessage": "2017-05-23T09:40:21.181Z bea1b956-3f9b-11e7-93c8-5503fb925252 Task timed out after 30.00 seconds"
```

Here is my VPC configuration in my Lambda as I follow from [here](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_lambda_internet_vpc.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not Execute your lambda Function. But your lambda function looks like right one.

More than you not able to trigger event for download objects.

The following events are applicable

> RRSObjectLost, Put, Post, Copy, Complete Multipart Upload, Delete,
>   Delete Marker Created, ObjectCreate (All), ObjectDelete (All).

test your lambda by passing test data S3 put event from lambda console.

Comment: it gives me timeout but without any error whatsoever, probably it cant send the event to my server using my own httprequest?

Comment: The time out error is due to your memory configured for lambda. Set it to 512 Mb and log the request response as log.info("response"+response) and check in cloudwatch log

Comment: it is not logged unfortunately, i have updated my code now with the log but the log message is not shown during the test in aws lambda

Comment: Update your code with log statements. Attach lambda specific role

Comment: I have updated my code as you can see with the log statements

Comment: From the lambda log it says its been timed out in 30 seconds. Increase the time and try out. Make sure you have internet access

Comment: I already extend it to 90 seconds but still not working. I suspect it does not have correct vpc connection to internet access

Comment: Subnets attached to lambda are public or private. If it is private subnet you  need to launch nat gateway or nat instance. Make sure you have internet access in your VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Lambda functions run up to [5 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/).
What I would do:

1. Replace the the whole Lambda code with single log statement, just to make sure logging is working as expected or troubleshoot using "Troubleshooting Scenario 1" from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html).
2. With working logging:

   1. Modify your Lambda code by replacing `e.printStackTrace();` with logging calls and a logging statement in the beginning then trigger you lambda again.
   2. Set meaningful Apache HttpClient timeouts using [official doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout), so that your http call does not exceed 5 minutes.

   If you get network related error like SocketTimeoutException, check your Lambda configuration against [Internet Access for Lambda Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html).

Comment: I am not sure that even my code of sending simple POST request to internet is allowed in Lambda. I tried to set VPC for the lambda using [this](https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7) and [this](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_lambda_internet_vpc.html) but still no success

Comment: It will be useful, if you can get any error log and provide some screen shots with your configuration.

Comment: check the updated question, hope it could help you to know whats wrong